# Op-Amp not working as a integrator

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, amplifier, bjt, ltspice

[image: Frequency response circuit]

[image: Frequency response]
[image: Circuit for transient response]
[image: transient response]

I designed a simple 2 stage op amp. Now I am trying to make it work as an integrator as shown in image 1.
The frequency response as shown in image 2 is as expected and I am operating between the cutoff frequency and the 0dB frequency.

When I apply a sine wave of 5kHz as shown in image 3 expecting a cosine wave at the output, it doesn't work for some reason. You can see the output waveform doesn't make sense to me.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not enough output current to drive the cap

Comment: You should probably add a power gain stage on the output; replace that output stage with a class-AB bipolar output and you should see some improved performance.

Comment: Let”s see Ic=20uA=CdV/dt won’t work. Add a complementary Darlington, or raise the impedances a few orders of magnitude or change the mirrors., add a curent limiter. Then you might have a real op amp. Back in school days this was a 20 minute exam design question.

Comment: I would take a step back and replace the opamp circuit with an **ideal** opamp, in a simulator that's simply a vcvs (voltage controlled voltage source) and give it a gain of 1000. Then try to get what you want (sine in, cosine out). When that all works, look at the output current of your idea opamp, your transistor opamp needs to be able to deliver the same current. Can you opamp do that? My point: you first need to determine the **requirements** for your opamp before designing it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the suggestions. I looked into it and the op amp was not providing enough output current so I added a class AB amplifier at the output. The results are better now but there is a slight problem which I am going to ask in another questions.